# How to draw a boxplot from a DataFrame with lists in values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a following structure of the dataframe:

```
data = [
    [12, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]],
    [14, [0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2]]
    # .... and so on
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'distribution'])
```

How to build a boxplot chart(s) where:

1. each box-and-whisker will show the distribution (using the box/whiskers/outliers) of the `distribution` column above for each index
2. each box-and-whisker will aggregate the distributions with the same `index` (e.g. if the `index` value is the same, the `distribution` will be merged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas' `.explode()` to convert the pesky lists into a long form dataframe. Seaborn is by far the easiest sway to create a matplotlib-style boxplot from a dataframe. Seaborn will automatically group values belonging to the same 'index'.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [
    [12, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]],
    [14, [0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2]]
    # .... and so on
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'distribution'])
sns.boxplot(data=df.explode('distribution'), x='index', y='distribution', palette='magma')
```

[image: seaborn boxplot from lists in columns]